# Mongodb sharding is NOT recovered after power off accident

Tags: mongodb, sharding, recover

I'm running 4 vms (centos) on a single machine (Windows 2008 R2). The 4 vms are setup as below:
1 mongos
1 mongo configure server
2 mongod as sharding servers

OK, everything was fine before a power off accident. When the power came back, I did manually reboot all the VMs, and found the sharding setting is gone. I mean, the mongos can talk to the configure server, but somehow the sharding data is lost and it show the database is not sharded.

I setup the sharding based on documents from mongodb websites (e.g. running some command in mongo shell to enable sharding for the db and each collection). Do I need to do all the mongo shell commands again after rebooting? Or is it supposed to recover automatically once the sharding is enabled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've established a sharded cluster, it is certainly supposed to stay configured, even if servers fail, even if they all fail at the same time.  Restarting the servers should bring everything up just the way it was before the outage.  Based on your description, it is difficult to reason what might have gone wrong.  A dump of the config database, and the log files of all the affected servers, would be necessary to analyze what happened.  This should perhaps be filed as a ticket with MongoDB support.

(It is, by the way, recommended to run three config servers rather than a single one, for availability reasons.  But even so, even a single server should recover just fine after having failed.  The three-server recommendation is only to make sure that there's always a live config server even if one of them should fail.)